# Error while processing route error in ember.js with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create an app using ember.js and ember-data, using the following versions:

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.7.0
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.9
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.2.1
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.0
```

I'm using the RESTAdapter to connect to an api I wrote using node.js.

As soon as I load the app I keep getting the following error:

```
Error while processing route: students undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor/ember-data.js:12006:34
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor/ember.js:45818:16)
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor/ember.js:45830:17)
    at publish (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor/ember.js:45801:11)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor/ember.js:29069:9
    at DeferredActionQueues.invoke (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor/ember.js:634:18)
    at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor/ember.js:684:15)
    at Object.Backburner.end (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor/ember.js:147:27)
    at Object.Backburner.run (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor/ember.js:202:20)
at apply (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor/ember.js:18382:27)
```

Here's the code I'm using (loaded in the same order I pasted it):

**app.js**

```
var App = window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: false,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true
});
```

**store.js**

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:3000',

    serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
        primaryKey: function(type) {
            return '_id';
        },

        serializeId: function(id) {
            return id.toString();
        }
    })
});
```

**models/student.js**

```
App.Student  = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    nationality: DS.attr('string'),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date')
});
```

**routes/app_route.js**

```
App.StudentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('student');
    }
});
```

**router.js**

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('students', {path: '/'});
});
```

And the following is the response of the API:

```
{
    students: [
        {
            nationality: "Lorem",
            lastName: "Doe",
            firstName: "John",
            _id: "53f87200f3750319b4791235",
            createdAt: "2014-08-23T10:50:40.661Z"
        },
        {
            nationality: "Lorem",
            lastName: "Doe",
            firstName: "John",
            _id: "53f87299f3750319b4791234",
            createdAt: "2014-08-23T10:50:40.661Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

It looks like the store is not loading the data from the API, but the JSON data format looks fine. Any idea of what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I had the exact same error, which started when I wasn't using 1.7.0 but 1.8.0-beta.1 ... switching back to 1.7.0 fixed it for me. Not sure why you are having the problem though :(

Comment: I believe you need to use a string in `primaryKey` instead of a function [based on the docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#property_primaryKey). Something like `primaryKey: '`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after searching more on Stack Overflow, I've figured out that the serializer has now to be in a separate class than the RESTAdapter, so the working code is the following:

**store.js**

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:3000'
});

App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: '_id',
    serializeId: function(id) {
        return id.toString();
    }
});
```

Comment: For those using `ember-cli`, check out my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an updated answer for people using `ember-cli`.

```
ember g adapter application #=> creates app/adapters/application.js
ember g serializer application #=> creates app/serializers/application.js
```

In `app/adapters/application.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RestAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:3000'
});
```

In `app/serializers/application.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id',
  serializeId: function(id) {
    return id.toString();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error, and it had nothing to do with any of the usual suspects.

In coffeescript, I had started defining a model.

```
 App.Cost = DS.Model.extend
   amount:         DS.attr 'number'
   active:         DS.attr 'boolean'
```

To create a second model, I c/p my first model in and deleted the attributes:

```
  App.Cost = DS.Model.extend
```

The went back and tried to run a seemingly unrelated model

```
 localhost:3000/products
```

Which resulted in the error

```
 Error while processing route: products.index
```

Simply making sure my model was named correctly solved the error:

```
 App.Cost = DS.Model.extend(...)
 App.Price = DS.Model.extend(...)   <- instead of repeating the Cost model
```

This was re-produceable, so I thought it might be helpful to others.